# could not find driver php&pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all I'd like to mention, that I looked at every one post about 'could not find driver';

I'm getting this exception

```
 could not find driver
```

when I run this command

```
 $dbh = new \PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

First of all, I'm using backslash before PDO because I'm in different namespace.

2) This command works all right on my different project on the same server (On that project I am not using any namespaces though)

3) Server is running on ubuntu

4) modules PDO and pdo_mysql are loaded (otherwise the 2) won't work)

5) the same code works on my localhost XAMP (windows) all right

Now I am quite desperate where else to look (and I've searched all related topics here on SO), so do you have any suggestions where's the problem?

Comment: no, I looked at that topic too and php_pdo_mysql module is loaded + my other project won't be working if otherwise

Comment: What does `print_r(\PDO::getAvailableDrivers())` say? Is there `mysql`?

Comment: output is Array([0] => sqlite)

Comment: which is weird? i am using mysql